# Is there a way to split an image/video file into parts and compress certain parts?

Tags: compression, image-compression

I am working on an app and we are uploading a small file to figure out the users connection and based off that we are compressing the video/image files so they upload quickly. Is there a way to upload part of a video or image file and compress the other parts of it more than the first part of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitrate (translates directly to file size) is a very flexible parameter that you can use when compressing video.

By flexible, I mean that this can be changed continuously or at any time when compressing video, which means, different parts of the video can be compressed to require higher or lower bandwidth - this also has a proportional consequence on the quality of video.

So whatever tool you are currently using for compressing video, please explore the bitrate setting options it provides and try to play with it depending on your available bandwidth. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to answer your question without more context information, but let me try.

Instead of compressing after checking the users connection, you could use any compression algorithm that allows for quality scalability and embedded codestreams. For instance, with JPEG2000 you can define several quality layers, each of which can be defined by a target bit rate. Your app could then send the first layer to estimate the link speed and then send as many layers as you can afford. The user could later upload the missing layers as needed. Kakadu is an implementation of JPEG2000 that lets you do this, although it may require some time to figure out the correct invocation.
Depending on your particular problem, you may also want to take a look at the JPIP protocol of JPEG2000 for interactive transmission.

In addition to JPEG2000, you may want to take a look at the scalable extensions of the h264 (SVC) and HEVC (SHVC) video coders.

Finally, if you don't mind wanting some time and bandwidth, you could send any data for probing the speed and compress the images any way you like afterwards (:

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the raw video frames into chunks, say 2 secs per chunk. Every time you just encode one chunk with closed GOP compression. You can upload these bitstream files separately. This is how Youtube or Netflix handle video streaming.